# kvlang : Builder.load_string issue

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I was just trying to make a small hello world program as given below. Why nothing gets displayed.

```
# File: main.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp 

KV = '''
# File: clock.kv
<aClock@BoxLayout>:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  Label:
    color: 1,0,1,1
    text: '00:00:00'

<myClock> :
  aClock:
'''


class myClock(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Builder.load_string(KV)
    myClock().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
<AClock@BoxLayout>:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  Label:
    color: 1,0,1,1
    text: '00:00:00'

AClock:  # This is going to be the return value of Builder.load_string()
'''


class MyClock(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClock().run()
```

`App` is not a widget, so you can't do this:

```yaml
<myClock> :
  aClock:
```

And in Kivy, PEP8 is constraint rather than style. All widgtes' class name *must* starts with upper case. So `aClock` must be `AClock`.

And you should implement `build()` and make it return a widget. (There is a case that `build()` doesn't have to return a widget, though.)

#### separating into two files

```yaml
# myclock.kv

<AClock@BoxLayout>:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  Label:
    color: 1,0,1,1
    text: '00:00:00'

AClock:
```

```py
# main.py

from kivy.app import App

class MyClock(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClock().run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question. If I have seperate .kv file with name myclock.kv instead of writing build function I just define the class myClockApp with no implementations. How to recreate same kind of working in above code (provided kv file is loaded using load_string) and associating the kv content with class in python

Comment: I updated the code. If you have a file named `myclock.kv`, it will be automatically loaded. So you shouldn't load it explicitly. If you do that, the kv file is loaded twice, which probably break your widgets.